# A soft substance that can be used to seal a seam between a bathtub and a wall

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, terminology

I need to go shopping for a certain thing, but do not know a proper English word for it.

It is a soft substance usually sold in a tube that can be used to seal a seam between a bathtub and a wall. It becomes harder and watertight soon after it is applied, but remains elastic enough so that it does not crack because of small bathtub movements.

How is it called?

Comment: Your "product description" is excellent. The salesperson at the dealers' would appreciate hearing this PD, not a researched 'name.' As a customer, go ahead and ask for what you want by its PD.

Comment: [Grouting](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=grouting&client=firefox-a&hs=IYz&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0WijUemnIKWf0QWpnoCwCQ&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=960#client=firefox-a&hs=iDK&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=bath+grouting&oq=bath+grouting&gs_l=img.3..0i24.5636.6149.0.6355.5.5.0.0.0.0.88.308.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.14.img.IC29pxyJT3E&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.d2k&fp=38d482e3b78657d8&biw=1920&bih=960)

Comment: Not grout, caulk.  Particularly, bathtub caulk. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The substance is *silicone*, or *silicone caulk*, and what you do is *silicone* or *caulk* your bath (or kitchen) with a *[caulking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caulking) gun* or *tube*.

Answer (score 2):

"Caulk" is an American term for what we call "sealant" in British English. We purchase tubes of silicone sealant and we put them in sealant guns and use them to seal gaps.